# Zend Framework Custom route for multilanguage

Tags: php, zend-framework, multilingual

this is my current route

```
routes.index.route = "/:lang/:controller/:action*"
routes.index.defaults.controller = index
routes.index.defaults.action = index
routes.index.defaults.lang = en
```

But it doesn't work, I need something like `/:lang/:controller/:action` can someone help me?Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your syntax looks a little sparse try:

```
resources.router.routes.index.route = "/:lang/:controller/:action*"
resources.router.routes.index.defaults.module = default
resources.router.routes.index.defaults.controller = index
resources.router.routes.index.defaults.action = index
resources.router.routes.index.defaults.lang = en
```

you also need to define the module even if it just the 'default' (read no module) module.